# Unable to send mail using Mail:Sender in perl 

Tags: perl, scripting

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mail::Sender;

$::sender = new Mail::Sender
  {smtp => 'xx.xx.xx.xxx', from => 'abc@xyz.com'};

$::sender->MailFile({to => 'abc@xyz.com',
  subject => 'Here is the file',
  msg => "I'm sending you the list you wanted.",
  });
```

Comment: Can you post the error message you get, please?

Comment: Sidenote: please `my $var = ...` and not `$::var = ...`. There are use cases for the latter, but not this one.

Comment: Stamm: I am getting no error for this one ......

Comment: Can you ask this module to die on errors? Or you could get the return value from the method and look it up in the docs.

Comment: Try adding `print $::sender->{'error_msg'}` at the end of your script.

Comment: Dallaylaen : With my i get this error ..............................                                  "my" variable $sender masks earlier declaration in same scope at C:\Documents and Settings\infodba\Desktop\parl\senderma
il.pl line 6.
Can't call method "MailFile" on an undefined value at C:\Documents and Settings\infodba\Desktop\parl\sendermail.pl line
6.

Comment: IF i use $sender only i got this error ............Global symbol "$sender" requires explicit package name at C:\Documents and Settings\infodba\Desktop\parl\sendermail.pl l
ine 4.
Global symbol "$sender" requires explicit package name at C:\Documents and Settings\infodba\Desktop\parl\sendermail.pl l
ine 6.
Execution of C:\Documents and Settings\infodba\Desktop\parl\sendermail.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Stamm :  I got error as No File name specified .......

Comment: Sorry, I hurried a bit. You should generally *declare* a variable as `my $var = ...` (or just `my $var;`) and then *use* it without my. The variable exists till the end of code block, i.e. `use strict; { my $foo = 1; print $foo; }; print $foo; ` prints 1 and then dies. See `perldoc -f my` for more.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't send any file. Try using this:

```
$::sender->MailFile({to => 'abc@xyz.com',
  subject => 'Here is the file',
  msg => "I'm sending you the list you wanted.",
  file => 'full_path_to_your_attachment'});
```

The [Mail::Sender documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jenda/Mail-Sender-0.8.16/Sender.pm#MailFile) says that the `file` argument is mandatory.

Comment: Can i use Mailmsg instead OF MailFile here ?

Comment: @kanwarpal
Yes, just type `$::sender->MailMsg(...)` instead of `$::sender->MailFile(...)`

Comment: ok i have done Mailmsg ...... Now i am getting .... Service Not Available.Reply: ....... as a error . What should i do ?

Comment: Did you use a real address is the `smtp` field? Is your mail server correctly working? Can you ping it?

Comment: yeh i have tried the domain name and ip both . Yes mail server is working perfectly.

Comment: Please try `ping your.mail.server.com` and `telnet your.mail.server.com 25` and post the results.